# How to override an abstract class level method of an objective-c class in a swift class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-c class level method as follows

```
+(SObjectData *)createSObjectData:(NSDictionary *)soupDict{
@throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Must override %@ in a sub class",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)],userInfo:nil]
}
```

I want to override this method in a subclass of this in **swift**

I tried the following

```
override class func createSObjectData(soupDict:NSDictionary)->SObjectData
{
//some code
}
```

But its is giving me an error that

> method does not override any method from super class

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? FWIW, your sample methods have different names (the capitalization of the O), and the parameter's type is misspelled (NSDcitionary) but it's impossible to which (if either) is the issue without further information.

Comment: please check the updated question. thanks for the response @Arclite

Comment: There are no spelling and capitalization problem with the original code. thanq . But you can see the error message @Arclite.Now please help me

Comment: Is SObjectData a swift class or objectiveC class?

Comment: it is an Objective-c class @hariszaman and I added an import statement in  bridging header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fix syntax error in the method and make it look like

```
+(SObjectData *)createSObjectData:(NSDictionary *)soupDict
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Must override %@ in a sub class",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]userInfo:nil];
}
```

In your BaseClass.h

```
+(SObjectData *)createSObjectData:(NSDictionary *)soupDict;
```

In your BaseClass.m

```
+(SObjectData *)createSObjectData:(NSDictionary *)soupDict
{
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Must override %@ in a sub class",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]userInfo:nil];
}
```

In your swift class

```
override class func createSObjectData(soupDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> SObjectData
{
    return SObjectData();
}
```

**Update:**

If your are sure the dictionary is never nil use `NSDictionary * _Nonnull` on the other had if NSDictionary can be nil use  `NSDictionary * _Nullable` and update the swift code to `soupDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]` or `soupDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]?` respectively. In case NSDictionary is nil then use `guard let` for optional checking

Comment: thanks you @hariszaman
It is not resulting any error. please explain that why NSDictionary is not working as arguement ?

Comment: It is the way how objective c conversion to swift happens [NSObject : AnyObject] tells you it is a swift dictionary with key = NSObject and value = AnyObject . In swift counterpart of NSDictionary is Dictionary so [NSObject: AnyObject] is short form for Dictionary<NSObject : AnyObject>